# Getting the width of a newly added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the width of a newly added item using JavaScript or jQuery. I know if I need to bind an event to a newly added element I can use event delegation or the .on() method in jQuery. But in this case I’m not binding an event I just need to get the width of that element. How can I do that?

```
$('#box').width();    // won’t work
document.getElementById("box").width;     // won't work either
```

Comment: Jqueries `width()` function seems to work correct: http://jsfiddle.net/r23022sn/1/

Answer (score 2):

### To get the width

You can just use jQuery's `.width()` method:

```
$('#box').width() // Should give you the pixel width with no px/rem/%

// Or plain ol' Vanilla JS
document.getElementById('box').offsetWidth

// Or mix it up
$('#box')[0].offsetWidth
```

### Possible issues

- Make sure your element has been created, it is visible and you added it to the DOM.
- Your element contains floated elements or absolutely positioned elements and therefore has not gained any width.
- You're trying to retrieve the elements width prior to the DOM rendering.
- Make sure your element is not affected by any stylesheet and has somehow become inline.

### Loading issue

Make sure that your script is on the bottom of the page and/or you are using jQuery's `.ready()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box').width();
});

// Shorthand for the above
$(function(){
    $('#box').width();
});
```

### Demos

[VanillaJS Demo](http://jsbin.com/xibamo)

[jQuery Demo](http://jsbin.com/kuboha)

*If anyone can think of other issues or solutions please contribute to the answer.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
alert(window.getComputedStyle(box).width);
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.